# USB Device Detection in WinCE 6.0 Device using MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-ce

Can anyone please help me how to detect USB Device Connected to WinCE 6.0 Device and send some data to the same?

What i want is, Check if any USB Device is Connected to the WinCE 6.0 Device and send the data to the same device?

Thanks in Advance..!!